# Can I copy symbols from one font into another?

Tags: fonts

Is it possible to copy a Unicode symbol block from one font to another? For example, could I copy Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols from Cambria Math into Consolas? I need that nabla.

I need this for plain text and source code files, so using multiple fonts is not an option.